# How to upscale the video using resizer DMO

Tags: c++, winapi, video, directshow, dmo

I am using re sizer DMO to re-size the input video. when I downscale the video it works fine. But when i upscale the video to a size greater than the source rectangle, i get a blank screen.

Can anyone tell me how to set the output type properties to increase the output window

Comment: You are apparently interested in adding details to your question.

Comment: @RomanR.I did not understand your comment.

Comment: Upscaling is operational. Show some code to possibly identify issues.